# Calling random AKPlayers in AKSequencer with repeated random results

Tags: swift, audiokit, arc4random, aksequencer

This is a multiple audiofile playback project I am currently working on, where  multiple AKPlayers are played in a random order, through AKSequencer.

First, I have an array of filenames:

```
Let filenames = [“1.mp3”, “2.mp3, “3.mp3”, … “10.mp3”]
```

This is loaded on AKPlayer individually, to later call it in a random order:

```
Let players: [AKPlayer] = {
    Do {
        Let filenames = [“1.mp3”, “2.mp3, “3.mp3”, … “10.mp3”]
        Return try filenames.map { AKPlayer(audioFile: try AKAudioFile(readRileName: $0)) }
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}()
```

Then, I called AKPlayer through AKsequencer, by triggering it through ‘`playRandom`’ function:

```
Let sequencer = AKSequencer()
Let callbackInst = AKCallbackInstrument()

func playRandom() {
    let playerIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
    players[playerIndex].play()
}

func addTracks() {
    let track = sequencer.newTrack()!
    track.add(noteNumber: 48, velocity: 127, position: AKDuration(beats: 0), duration: AKDuration(beats: 16), channel: 0)
    track.setMIDIOutput(callbackInst.midiIn)
    callbackInst.callback = { status, note, vel in
        guard status == .noteOn else { return }
        self.playRandom()
        }
    }
```

Lastly, I set AKPlayer as AudioKit.output, and started the sequencer.
So far this was successful! The sequencer plays AKPlayer seamlessly, in a random order.

But I wanted to try different kind of randomness: repeating randomly selected player **2 or 3 times**. (like 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, …) Right now, ‘`playRandom`’ simply chooses different AKPlayer on each repeat.

As one solution, thanks to StackOverFlow masters, I tried something like:

```
class RandomWithRepeats {
var range: ClosedRange<Int>
var repeatRange: ClosedRange<Int>
var repeatCount = 0
var value = 0

init(range: ClosedRange<Int>, repeatRange: ClosedRange<Int>) {
    self.range = range
    self.repeatRange = repeatRange
}

// generate a random number in a range
// Just use Int.random(in:) with Swift 4.2 and later
func random(in range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound + 1))) + range.lowerBound
}

func nextValue() -> Int {
    // if repeatCount is 0, its time to generate a new value and
    // a new repeatCount
    if repeatCount == 0 {
        // For Swift 4.2, just use Int.random(in:) instead
        value = self.random(in: range)
        repeatCount = self.random(in: repeatRange)
    }

    repeatCount -= 1
    return value
}
}
```

And then I modified `playRandom` function like:

```
func playRandom() {
    Let rand = randomWithRepeats(range: 1…players.count, repeatRange: 2…3)
    Do { players[rand.nextValue()].play() }
}
```

Turns out, this is the exact same result because the playRandom function itself triggered (by AKSequencer) each repeat, so it doesn’t actually ‘repeat’ random AKPlayer 2 or 3 times. Can I solve this issue in a different way? Much appreciated. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job of the `RandomWithRepeats` class is to keep track of when to deliver you a different `AKPlayer` instance, but you are creating a new instance of `RandomWithRepeats` each time you call `playRandom()`, so it can't keep track of anything.

Create a single instance of `RandomWithRepeats` when you create the array of players and use this instance in your `playRandom()` method.

```
let rand = RandomWithRepeats(range: 0 ... players.count, repeatRange: 2 ... 3)

func playRandom() {
     try? players[rand.nextValue()].play() 
}
```

For a cleaner solution, you might encapsulate the logic of `RandomWithRepeats` together with the `AKPlayer` array into a single class, such as a `RandomlyRepeatingPlayer` class.